# How to decrypt files in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, esb

What would be the best approach to decrypt files in WSO2?

I was thinking about using GPG to do that, does anybody has any other idea?

Comment: effectively you have two options - create a service for that or a custom mediation.. the underlying decryption is not in scope of the ESB itself..

Answer (score 0):

You will first need is to download a cryptographic software to be able to encrypt some files in your local system. **For example (gpg4win).**

You will then need to create a key pair, it will be used later on to encrypt.

`<property value="example@example.com" name="emailKey"/>
<property value="C:/trainning/folder1/" name="inputFilePath"/><property value="C:/trainning/folder2/" name="outputFilePath"/>
<property value="example.txt" name="inputFileName"/>
<property value="encryptedExampleTXT.gpg" name="outputFileName"/>
<property expression="fn:concat($ctx:inputFilePath,$ctx:inputFileName)" name="inputPathAndFileName"/>
<property expression="fn:concat($ctx:outputFilePath,$ctx:outputFileName)" name="outputPathAndFileName"/>
<script language="js">
<![CDATA[var command = "gpg -v --no-secmem-warning -r " + String(mc.getProperty('emailKey')) + " --always-trust --armor --output " + String(mc.getProperty('outputPathAndFileName')) + " --encrypt " + String(mc.getProperty('inputPathAndFileName'));
print(command.toString());
var process = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);process.waitFor();]]>
</script>`

I have posted a step by step solution on Medium if you want to get more details.
https://medium.com/@antoniocarlosreis/how-to-encrypt-files-using-gpg-in-wso2-esb-1b612dc7abde